# Как соообщить о необходимой MVC++ при запуске программы?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Как сделать, что бы при запуске программы появлялось сообщение о отсутствии необходимого пакета Microsoft Visual C++  для работы программы вместо сообщений об отсутствующих DLL ?
Как это реализовать, если без необходимого MVC++ программа вобще не может запуститься?

Comment: Так обычно же как раз и вылезает ошибка о, например, отсутствующей dll, разве нет?

Comment: @Matty, ну так нужно, что появилось именно сообщени об отсутствующей MVC, а не о не найденой DLL

Comment: Может быть, стоит подумать о создании setup.exe, например, с помощью Inno Setup. И в процессе установки вашей программы говорить, что на компьютере должен быть установлен MSVC. У студии кстати тоже есть какое-то средство для создания установочного exe

Answer (score 1):

Проверить соответствующие ветки реестра:
См.: 
[Detect if Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed)

В случае отсутствия необходимого пакета, выдать предупреждение.

Comment: Sublihim, но как выйдет предупреждение, если прога не запускается без необходимого MVC ?

Comment: @Антон. WinAPI никто не отменял. MessageBox, к примеру.Или собственное простое диалоговое окно на чистом WinAPI. Т.е., как вариант, ваша программа состоит из 2-х частей: простой загрузчик на WinAPI и, собственно, ваша программа. Стартует загрузчик, проверяет, что надо. В случае "все плохо" показывает сообщение, в случае "все хорошо" запускает вашу программу.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы программа перестала зависеть от VCRT*.dll, ее нужно собрать со статическим runtime. См. своства проекта ./ C/C++ / Code generation / Runtime library. Выбрать runtime НЕ содержащий в названии DLL.

Понятно, что с ним не удастся собрать никакую оконную библиотеку (ни MFC, ни Qt ...), но единственный MessageBox, можно показать и средствами чистого WinApi.

Comment: Для этого надо поменять /MD на /MT и /MDd на /MTd.